# How to emit a signal when its member emits one?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

For example, I have a class `Document` which has a private member `QUndoStack` which has a signal `cleanChanged()`. When the member emits the signal, I wish the containing class `Document` emits a signal with the same name or the signal from the member can be transferred to the containing class. Thus the outside know `cleanChanged` happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to connect Document with QUndoStack's signal. You don't need to create a slot and emit a signal from it. You can just add signal to Document and connect Document's signal with QUndoStack's one.

As soon as QUndoStack will emit signal, also Document will do.

**EDIT:**

here is an example. It probably won't compile, its purpose is just to show you the trick.

```
class Document: public QObject
{
        QUndoStack *m_QUndoStack;
        public:

        Document(QObject *parent): QObject(parent), m_QUndoStack(new QUndoStack(this))
        {
                //here we do the trick:
                connect(m_QUndoStack, SIGNAL(somesignal()), this, SIGNAL(somesignal());
        }

signals:
        void somesignal();
};
```

Comment: How not to create a slot and emit a signal from it? Would you please show me a little code?